# Console throws an error with useReducer on a calculator app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

My first try on working with `useReducer()` on a calculator mini-project. But is throws an error whenever I try clicking on buttons:

[image: console errors]

line 136 (const inside App function) in my code looks alright?

```
function App() {
  const [{ currentOperand, previousOperand, operation }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {}
  )
```

I'm using reducer function here with switch statements for math operations

```
function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {switch(type)...}
```

dispatch is used on buttons like this

```
<DigitButton digit = "0" dispatch={dispatch}/>
```

and the exported component of buttons

```
export default function DigitButton ({ dispatch, digit }) {
 return <button className="btn" onClick = {() => dispatch({ type: actions.add_digit, payload: { digit}})}>{digit}</button>
};
```

and the imports are here just in case

```
import { useReducer } from 'react'
import DigitButton from './DigitButton'
import OperationButton from './OperationButton'
import './App.css'
```

I'm a beginner so I'm totally lost and can't figure what even might be the problem.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/keyc9/calculator-react/useReduce-fail?workspaceId=3b0441f9-e19b-4073-b6e1-34e82bbdca03&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.css&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cleg68nbr000fg1gg21hq6lea%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522cleg68p8h00152a6ep0qse95w%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cleg68p8h00152a6ep0qse95w%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cleg68p8i00162a6ejwe2pfi3%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522cleg68p8h00152a6ep0qse95w%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522cleg68p8h00152a6ep0qse95w%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, for example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new to asking questions so didn't think of it
I've updated the link

Comment: You don't have a default case in your switch and your reducer is returning `undefined`